# <%=Html.Button%> parameters

Tags: c#, html, button

I have a **Html button** as follows:

```
<%=Html.Button("javascript:onSave();", CommonResource.Save, "SaveButton")%>
```

Where:

```
parameter1 - action  
parameter2 - name   
parameter3 - id
```

How can I add parameter for **CSS class**? I tried doing this:

```
<%=Html.Button("javascript:onSave();", CommonResource.Save, "SaveButton",new { @class="save" })%>
```

but that does not work. I only get the looks but no action is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at your implementation of `Html.Button` as it isn't a standard HtmlHelper.

It probably doesn't have a parameter for htmlAttributes, in which case you could use this implementation, which does!

```
public static class HtmlButtonExtension 
{
  public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, string text,
                                 IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
  {
      var builder = new TagBuilder("button");
      builder.InnerHtml = text;
      builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like ASP.NET MVC. If so please tag your question appropriately. There's no `Button` helper in the standard MVC library so I guess that this is some custom or third party helper you are using. If there's no overload allowing you to pass htmlAttributes then this cannot be done.